# How to open CSV file in Excel with correct columns

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I try to open a CSV file with Excel using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel libary.
And it works fine but all the text is in one column with the delimiter ";".
Here an example:

```
Id;Name;Zeit
1;Name1;21.05.2019 09:21:04
3;Name2;21.05.2019 09:21:04
```

This is the code I used to open the CSV in Excel:

```
object missing = Type.Missing;
Excel.Application ex = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wbs = ex.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\users\langenwa\desktop\File.csv", 0, false, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, ";", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
Excel.Worksheet mSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wbs.Worksheets[1];
ex.Visible = true;
```

Thanks for any help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is Excel Interop really mandatory here? For simple csv like that you can use a CSV Helper or any real library that deals with CSV. It will be easier to code. And you will be able to deploy on a server that doesn't have a Excel (license are expensive on server).

Comment: Why are you using Excel Interop? Do you want to automate a user's Excel instance? There's little reason to use Excel otherwise. Libraries like CsvHelper can read CSVs using any delimiter and even CSVs with "unfortunate" features like comment lines. Libraries like Epplus can generate real Excel files without calling Excel itself.

Comment: Interop Excell can be incredibly slow. Could you describe a little bit the context? are you importing data from a csv ? Do you need to generate an output? What is the format of this output? Are you trying to ease the opening of a file in Excel for an user that will have issue finding it or setting delimiter and column type?

Comment: Thanks for that fast answers! I want to open that csv in Excel because I want to add some filters and font settings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv file works fine in my excel, likely your system has a different default seperator. You can override this.

try to add this at the top of the csv file:

```
sep=;
```

- note that this only works when opening csv in excel

See these answers for more details: https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files